# How do I select a Google Sheets cell by its string value and delete it in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function in Google Apps Script for a Google Sheet containing data that will automatically be updated every month. I want a cell in column A with value '1/30/3800' to be deleted (i.e. I want to set its value to ''.) I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify the cell based on its string value, NOT based on its position in the spreadsheet. I've tried these two methods:

1)

```
function forecastUpdate() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  for (let i = 0; i <- data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] === '1/30/3800') {
      data[i] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

2. 

```
function forecastUpdate() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  for (let value of data) {
    if (value === '1/30/3800') {
      value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

It says it executes, but it doesn't - nothing updates in my sheet. Any tips?!
Note 1: The cell that I am trying to clear has a value derived from a QUERY formula in the Google Sheet. Not sure if that matters.
Note 2: I cannot select it by its position (A41) in the sheet because its position will change every month.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Range.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
. Also `data` is a 2D array here. So you need to get the value correctly.

Assuming that the value '1/30/3800' is a string and not interpreted as a date, the following should work.

```
function forecastUpdate() {
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1];
    let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    let foundAtRow;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let row = data[i];
        let colA = row[0];
        if (colA === '1/30/3800') {
            foundAtRow = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundAtRow) {
        throw new Error('Match not found.');
    }

    sheet.getRange('A' + foundAtRow).setValue('');
}
```

Depending on the formula, you may not be allowed to update the cell value

Comment: Thank you @Karan! I keep getting stuck at the Match not found error. For all the code I've written to try to solve this, the error I always get is actually locating the match. I ran a console.log for "data" and saw that the date has the long format, but even when I replace the short date with "Thu Jan 30 3800 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Function occurs once month using a daily trigger it looks for strings in column equal to '1/30/3800' and sets the value of each cell to null.

```
function forecastUpdate(e) {
  if (e['day-of-month'] == 1) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
    const sr = 2;//data start row
    const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 1).getDisplayValues()
    vs.forEach(r => {
      if (r[0] == '1/30/3800') {
        r[0] = '';
      }
    });
    sh.getRange(sr, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
  }
}


function createDailyTrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'forecastUpdate').lendth == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('forcastUpdate').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
  }
}
```

[Time Based Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I run this it gives me this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'day-of-month' of undefined"
Just FYI this is the first time I've ever used Google Apps Script or Javascript!

Comment: Yes that's because it is meant to be run from the daily trigger.  You could run it through an intermediate function by supplying the needed properties in an object that you supply to the function as a parameter to populate the e as a trigger would do